# Prove that if vi is a basis of the column space of A then f(vi) is a basis of the column space of f(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

I met a problem from the liner algebra test of our school. The question is:
Consider the following function $f$ that takes any matrix $A$ as argument and returns a matrix
$$f\left(A\right)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}A&A\\A&-A\end{pmatrix}$$

Now Let $\left\{{\boldsymbol v}_{\mathbf1}\boldsymbol,{\boldsymbol v}_{\mathbf2}\boldsymbol,\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.{\boldsymbol v}_{\mathbf d}\right\}$ be a basis of the column space of $A$, where the column space of $A$ is the span of the column vectors of $A$. Show that
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}\\{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}\end{pmatrix}\boldsymbol,\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol,\begin{pmatrix}{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}\\{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}\end{pmatrix}\boldsymbol,\begin{pmatrix}{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}\\\boldsymbol-{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}\end{pmatrix}\boldsymbol,\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol,\begin{pmatrix}{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}\\\boldsymbol-{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
is a basis of the column space of $f(A)$.
As I think, as $f(A)$ shows, isn't it obvious to see that the basis of the column space of $f(A)$ is
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}&{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}\\{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}&\boldsymbol-{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf1}\end{pmatrix}\boldsymbol,\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol.\boldsymbol,\begin{pmatrix}{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}&{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}\\{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}&\boldsymbol-{\mathbf v}_{\mathbf d}\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Then after a simple split, we can get the answer, right? (just a joke...)
In fact I have no idea how to prove this 'obvious' question, could you give me some hints on that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exercise in "writing mathematics". Your joking logic actually translates to the right thinking, but for some adjustment in entries. Acknowledging the fact that the $v_i$ are not the columns but rather a column basis is important. Writing the obvious-looking is a skill in math. Besides, not everything looking obviously true is mathematically true, though your thought is fine.

Let us see how we would do this. First, we want to show that some set is a basis for the column space of $f(A)$. Showing something as a basis requires two things : spanning and linear independence. So both need to be proved.

First let us prove spanning. Take a column of $f(A)$. What does it look like? Either we pick it from the "left set" of blocks or the "right" set. So, if $\mathbf{c}$ is a column of $A$, then a column of $f(A)$ either looks like $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{c} \\ \mathbf{c}\end{bmatrix}$ or like $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {c} \\ \mathbf{-c}\end{bmatrix}$, where $-\mathbf{c}$ is $-1 \times \mathbf{c}$. Since $\{v_i\}$ is a basis of the columns of $A$, we have $\mathbf c = \sum c_iv_i$ for some scalars $c_i$. Now, we note that,for example:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf c \\ \mathbf {-c}\end{bmatrix} = \sum \frac{c_i}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix}v_i \\ -v_i\end{bmatrix}
$$

And therefore the set given to you spans the columns on the "right side" of $f(A)$. For the left side see something similar by yourself. This proves spanning.

---

For linear independence, assume that some linear combination $\sum c_i \begin{bmatrix}v_i \\ v_i\end{bmatrix} + \sum d_i \begin{bmatrix}v_i \\ -v_i\end{bmatrix}$ is the zero vector of size $2n$(where $n$ is the dimension of $A$). Now consider the "top half" of this equality, and it reads : $\sum (c_i + d_i) v_i = 0$ , where the zero vector has size $n$. Similarly, the "bottom half" of this equality reads $\sum(c_i-d_i)v_i = 0$.

Now, the $v_i$ are linearly independent, this forces allthe above coefficients to be zero. Hence, $c_i +d_i = c_i - d_i = 0$ for all $i$, therefore $c_i=d_i = 0$ for all $i$, showing linear independence of the set.

And thus the set is a basis for the columns of $f(A)$.